# comparing Dates in java when used as keys in HashMap

Tags: java, date, hashmap

I was trying to use a HashMap with `java.util.Date` as keys, but I came across this odd issue. When doing the below, I'm printing false.

```
Date testDate = new Date(timeInLongFormat);

HashMap<Date,Integer> datesAndInts;
datesAndInts.put(testDate, 0);

Iterator iterator = datesAndInts.keySet().iterator();  

while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
    String key = iterator.next().toString();
    System.out.println("comparing " + testDate + "with " + key + " result is " + testDate.equals(key)); 
    // this call to equals() returns false.
    Integer testInt = datesList.get(key); // testInt is null, since the Date key cannot be found ...
}
```

I would have expected the Date inserted as key and the Date returned by keySet to be identical, but they are not. Is that a normal behaviour ? Why ? Should I implement my own subclass of Date only comparing the time or something ?

Comment: Check the formatting. Do `System.out.println("key"+key);` and `System.out.println("testDate"+testDate);` and see what they are.

Comment: @hichris123 You won't see any difference, because sysout will use the String representation of the Date object by calling `testDate.toString()` to print.

Comment: @ZouZou Yeah, I realized that after looking at the answers. I was thinking that somehow the formatting could have gotten messed up, like 1 December 2013 vs December 1 2013.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, it was a silly mistake I've made here :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing a `Date` object with a `String` one.

```
Iterator<Date> iterator = datesAndInts.keySet().iterator();  
while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
    Date key = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("comparing " + testDate + "with " + key + " result is " + testDate.equals(key)); 
    // this call to equals() returns true now.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing the date with the key in the HashMap (which would be the exact same Date object). You're comparing a Date with a String, which happens to be the result of calling `toString()` on the date. A Date and a String will never be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this will return false: you're comparing a `Date` with a `String`.

If you use `testDate.toString().equals(key)`, it returns true.

The very first check in `Date.equals()`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equal method of Date: `Date.equals(Object)` expects the `Object` is an instance of type `Date`, passing String is possible as it is an `Object` bu will result in `false`: The source says it:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
    }
```

Again keep remember that `toString()` method converts the Date object to string representation of form: `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`, so you might face unexpected results if you are to compare two `Date` instance in String representation.